# How to uncheck checkboxes on a button click?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have the following 3 input checkboxes, after checking the checkboxes, I would like to clear all the checked items after the "Clear Checkbox" button is clicked. I attempted the following but it doesn't work.

[**Stackblitz working Example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tz8dac?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)

**app.component.html**

```
<ul *ngFor="let d of data">
  <li>
    <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" />
    {{ d }}
  </li>
</ul>

<button (click)="myFunction()">Clear Checkbox</button>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {
  data = ['tea', 'coffe', 'soda'];
  public myFunction() {
    (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('checkbox')).checked === false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Try `<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('checkbox')).checked = false`, With `===`, you are making a comparison.

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine my bad, now it works but only changes value to one item

Comment: Yes because you are selecting by id, you can't have several HTML elements with same id, use class instead. Nimitt Shah answer gives details.

Comment: You should really investigate the Angular Way of doing this. This implementation will cause you headaches eventually..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it in an angular fashion and use `ViewChildren` instead. So attach a ref to your checkboxes and access them with `ViewChildren`, as this would be a perfect case for that. So I attached `chkboxes` to the input

```html
<input #chkboxes id="checkbox" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" />
```

I define the querylist:

```ts
@ViewChildren('chkboxes') chkboxes: QueryList<ElementRef>;
```

and to uncheck I loop the elements and set them to false:

```ts
myFunction() {
  this.chkboxes.forEach(x => x.nativeElement.checked = false)
}
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hkvdx3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Answer (score 4):

You can use `document.querySelectorAll()` to uncheck all the checkboxes.

[**StakBlitz Working Example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qugunl?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

In `myFunction`, you code should be as below:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox').forEach(_checkbox=>{
    (<HTMLInputElement>_checkbox).checked = false;
});
```

Also, make sure you are assinging `false` value (=) not checking (===)!

Comment: You still should make sure the `id` of the checkboxes are not all the same.

Comment: yea, I am not using `id`

Comment: In the question and in your StackBlitz example, all the checkboxes have the `id` `checkbox`.